# Can I include a logo image with Django 1.7 new site_header setting?

Tags: python, django, customization, admin

I put this line in my urls.py site:

```
admin.site.site_header = 'My Site <img src="/static/LOGO.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:10%">'
```

The img tag displays on the page.  Which I assume means the string is being HTML escaped.

Is there a command or setting to let the img tag work?

It would be disappointing if one still had to edit the template files to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

People how are looking for the solution they can try this. I have tried this in version 1.8 Django above.

**Override the admin base_site.html template**

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"><img src="{{site_header}}"/></a>

{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Save base_site.html in **templates->admin** folder if not create the folder.

Update TEMPLATES setting in your settings.py file

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
# Image to put at the top of the admin index page
admin.site.site_header = '/static/img/logo.png'
```